# Create chunks of big array based on element properties

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an issue and the way to solve it is by grouping the elements in my array based on their properties (the ID). Let me explain :

This is the given array :

```
[ { project_id: 'project:710f57c6bb18753dfeaad60b7a7437df',
    end_date: '2017-05-18',
    invoice_method: 'FixedFee',
    amount: '1.000000',
    price: '134.000000' },
  { project_id: 'project:710f57c6bb18753dfeaad60b7a7437df',
    start_date: '2017-06-01',
    subscription_cycle: 'Month',
    invoice_method: 'Subscription',
    amount: '1.000000',
    price: '49.000000' },

{ project_id: 'project:abcdefghijklmnop',
    start_date: '2017-06-01',
    subscription_cycle: 'Month',
    invoice_method: 'Subscription',
    amount: '1.000000',
    price: '49.000000'},

{ project_id: 'project:abcdefghijklmnop',
    start_date: '2017-06-01',
    subscription_cycle: 'Month',
    invoice_method: 'Subscription',
    amount: '1.000000',
    price: '49.000000'},
```

]

The first 2 elements in this big array have the same ID and the last 2 have the same ID, so the output I would like is something like :

```
//MAIN ARRAY
[ 
    //ONE CHUNK
    [
        { project_id: 'project:710f57c6bb18753dfeaad60b7a7437df',
        end_date: '2017-05-18',
        invoice_method: 'FixedFee',
        amount: '1.000000',
        price: '134.000000' },

        { project_id: 'project:710f57c6bb18753dfeaad60b7a7437df',
        start_date: '2017-06-01',
        subscription_cycle: 'Month',
        invoice_method: 'Subscription',
        amount: '1.000000',
        price: '49.000000' }
    ]

    //ONE CHUNK
    [
        { project_id: 'project:abcdefghijklmnop',
        start_date: '2017-06-01',
        subscription_cycle: 'Month',
        invoice_method: 'Subscription',
        amount: '1.000000',
        price: '49.000000'},

        { project_id: 'project:abcdefghijklmnop',
        start_date: '2017-06-01',
        subscription_cycle: 'Month',
        invoice_method: 'Subscription',
        amount: '1.000000',
        price: '49.000000'}

    ]


]
```

Comment: Not an exact duplicate, but potentially helpful: [How to group an array of objects by key](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40774906/1650337)

Comment: Try checking this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34890276/2223729

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are not asking for the code, here is an outline:

1. Create a [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) or object so that you can quickly find an id (as key) and the associated subarray (as value).
2. Iterate your data, and for each object look up the subarray in your Map/object. If there is no entry for that id yet, then create it for that id as an empty subarray. In either case push the current object to that subarray
3. Finally get all those subarrays from your Map/object and concatenate them to one final array.

Hidden code, in case you cannot make it work:

```js
const data = [ { project_id:'project:710f57c6bb18753dfeaad60b7a7437df', end_date: '2017-05-18',invoice_method: 'FixedFee',amount: '1.000000',price: '134.000000' },{ project_id: 'project:710f57c6bb18753dfeaad60b7a7437df',start_date: '2017-06-01',subscription_cycle: 'Month',invoice_method: 'Subscription',amount: '1.000000',price: '49.000000' },{ project_id: 'project:abcdefghijklmnop',start_date: '2017-06-01',subscription_cycle: 'Month',invoice_method: 'Subscription',amount: '1.000000',price: '49.000000'},{ project_id: 'project:abcdefghijklmnop',start_date: '2017-06-01',subscription_cycle: 'Month',invoice_method: 'Subscription',amount: '1.000000',price: '49.000000'}];

let map = new Map(data.map(o => [o.project_id, []]));
data.forEach(o => map.get(o.project_id).push(o));
let result = Array.from(map.values());

console.log(result);
```

Comment: @trincot. Just for curiosity, what you think of my solution instead?

Comment: @Raffobaffo, you just deleted it, but that looks like it uses this approach (using`acc` as the object to map id to subarray)

Comment: OK, I see people are posting code despite you saying you were not looking for code. If you want the code to go with this outline, let me know, and I'll add it.

Comment: @trincot yes, I deleted because the other posted solution is better. It uses a short-circuit evaluation while I was using an if nested in the reducer.

Comment: @Raffobaffo, that is a detail of the code. The OP was not asking for code anyway, but people don't read...

Comment: @trincot Yes right. Let's say I'm shy :P. It's just I started to "give back" answering questions here just 3 days ago, and I already been pretty stressed with other users downvoting or writing sense-less comments. So I seen an answer (in my opinion) a tick better was already posted, and I thought was better to remove mine. Long explanation

Answer (score 3):

Some like this for grouping based on key name.

Not exact but you can do like this. `.reduce()` will work.

Here keyName `project_id` is used to group array of objects.

```
const data = [ { project_id: 'project:710f57c6bb18753dfeaad60b7a7437df',
    end_date: '2017-05-18',
    invoice_method: 'FixedFee',
    amount: '1.000000',
    price: '134.000000' },
  { project_id: 'project:710f57c6bb18753dfeaad60b7a7437df',
    start_date: '2017-06-01',
    subscription_cycle: 'Month',
    invoice_method: 'Subscription',
    amount: '1.000000',
    price: '49.000000' },

{ project_id: 'project:abcdefghijklmnop',
    start_date: '2017-06-01',
    subscription_cycle: 'Month',
    invoice_method: 'Subscription',
    amount: '1.000000',
    price: '49.000000'},

{ project_id: 'project:abcdefghijklmnop',
    start_date: '2017-06-01',
    subscription_cycle: 'Month',
    invoice_method: 'Subscription',
    amount: '1.000000',
    price: '49.000000'
  }]

let result = data.reduce(function (r, a) {
        r[a.project_id] = r[a.project_id] || [];
        r[a.project_id].push(a);
        return r;
    }, []);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Check this solution, May this help you.

```
var initailArray = [ { project_id: 'project:710f57c6bb18753dfeaad60b7a7437df',
    end_date: '2017-05-18',
    invoice_method: 'FixedFee',
    amount: '1.000000',
    price: '134.000000' },
  { project_id: 'project:710f57c6bb18753dfeaad60b7a7437df',
    start_date: '2017-06-01',
    subscription_cycle: 'Month',
    invoice_method: 'Subscription',
    amount: '1.000000',
    price: '49.000000' },

{ project_id: 'project:abcdefghijklmnop',
    start_date: '2017-06-01',
    subscription_cycle: 'Month',
    invoice_method: 'Subscription',
    amount: '1.000000',
    price: '49.000000'},

{ project_id: 'project:abcdefghijklmnop',
    start_date: '2017-06-01',
    subscription_cycle: 'Month',
    invoice_method: 'Subscription',
    amount: '1.000000',
    price: '49.000000'},
];

let dummyObj = {};

initailArray.forEach((data)=>{
  if(!dummyObj[data.project_id]){
    dummyObj[data.project_id] = [data];
  }else{
    dummyObj[data.project_id].push(data);
  }
});

let finalResult = [Object.values(dummyObj)];

console.log("finalResult", finalResult);
```